# ASP.NET MVC XSS protection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

According to [OWASP XSS page](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules), one needs to use different XSS protection techniques for different contexts. However, in ASP.NET MVC Razor views, we only have the `@` sign to escape data in the context of HTML element inner content. What about HTML attributes, CSS, javascript contexts and others?

#### HTML element content

This is safe and will work as expected:

```
<div>@data</data>
```

#### HTML element attribute

This is not safe and can be exploited:

```
<div style="background: @color"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

While this is not safe:

```
<script>
    var value = @value;
</script>
```

Safe solution is:

```
<script>
    var value = @Json.Encode(value);
</script>
```

#### CSS

This is not safe and can be exploited:

```
<style>
    .box { background : @color; } 
</style>
```

Comment: When they say "contexts" they're not talking about Razor..  Razor just generates HTML.  Anything inside the @ tag will not render on the client (unless it's a specific function designed to do so).

Comment: this? https://wpl.codeplex.com/

Comment: @D.Rosado yes, AntiXSS seems like a solution, but what about "In .NET 4.0 a version of AntiXSS was included in the framework and could be enabled via configuration. In ASP.NET v5 a white list based encoder will be the only encoder"?

Comment: @AlexPolyankin Hey. Just curious what you are looking for in an answer... maybe I can elaborate further?

Comment: @Gray I've updated my answer with some examples. AFAIK HTML attributes and CSS properties are the only possible vulnerabilities here. I want to get recommended and production-ready solution. I am not a security expert however I think that using quotes around value is not 100% safe and can be exploited.

Comment: @AlexPolyankin Tried to better address your concerns through an update to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great thing about razor is that it does all the HTML encoding by default. Unless you use `@Html.Raw()`, it is pretty difficult to make your page vulnerable. You generally have to explicitly make variables render as html.

You also have [`Html.Encode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmlencode(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need it. There is also [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Regarding the updated vulnerable code:

```
@{var js = "alert(1);";}
<script>var value = @js</script>
```

I think you would be violating rule 0 with this code. You are inserting arbitrary strings into a script tag, and expecting it not to be executed. I actually get a syntax error (warning) with your example, but it will still run. If you wrapped it in quotes, you would be safe.

```
@{var js = "\"alert(1);";}
<script>var value = "@js"; alert(value);</script>
```

#### output:

```
&quot;alert(1);
```

Notice that the quote that I put in the string gets escaped to `&quot;`, making me unable to break out of the string, so I cannot inject js. 
I'd be interested to see if someone has a way of sanitizing this without putting it in quotes, but I am skeptical.

#### update 2:

Dealing with CSS

The examples you give are not about escaping strings, it is more about inserting untrusted CSS into your page. To do that, you will need something that can parse CSS. For example, it is not that you want the value to be encoded, you just want it not to include the dangerous stuff like url(javascript:), behavior, binding, etc. You'll need a CSS filtering tool for that.

HTML attributes

you are safe if you do this:

```
<div data-color="@color"></div>
```

Since razor encodes quotes, you won't be able to terminate the string early. That's as simple as it is to prevent XSS (barring some unknown vulnerability in razor). Your `Json.Encode()` uses the same idea.

BUT, you are doing somehting risky if you do this:

```
<div @attribute></div>
```

Again, it's not that you need an escaped string here, you want something that filters your attributes on any dangerous content. The fact is, that doing things this way is really messy, and I would advise against it. It is bad design because it is screwing up your separation of concerns and making it hard to secure your app from XSS. What you should do instead is add CSS classes if you want to change the style. If you need to set an attribute based on a variable in razor, use something else rather than injecting it into your HTML and hoping to filter it.

ex:

```
@{
var disabled = isDivDisabled ? "disabled" : "";
}
<div @disabled><div>
```

Comment: Updated question with example vulnerability.

Comment: @AlexPolyankin In my opinion, you are violating rule 0 by writing that code. You want to insert untrusted code into your javascript, but not run it? Huh? Put it in quotes, and then you'll be ok. I edited my answer. What else could go there **except** javascript?

Comment: I've made my own research and I am now sure that *doubles quotes and @* are enough to protect against XSS attacks in HTML attributes. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the accept. Proving it to yourself is always the best way to learn something.